# Print Queue implementation by linked list class C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am a student and not an advance developer. I faced an issue regarding to construct a program. I have tried a few things, but still could not solved it. The question came from an exam.
Apologize for this post, because my previous two posts were not accepted well. This time I tried, but got no success still for my posted issue.

### Question as follows

a) Write a class named Document to represent a document node in a print queue. It should contain a method name that returns the subject of the document and an abstract method called type that returns the document type. Derive from a document class two concrete classes named word document and pdf document.

b) Another class named Print Queue that is implemented as a linked list of Document objects. Print Queue should have a method named Push for adding a document to the end of the list, a method named pop for removing the first document from the list, and a method named DisplayContents for listing all of the documents in the Print Queue, reporting both the Name and Type of each element Print Queue should not use any standard library classes it should be own implementation of linked list.

### Here I have coded it that way:

```
class PrintQueue
{
    private Document head;

    private int size;
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return size;
        }
    }

    public void Push(Object data)
    {
        Document toAdd = new Document();
        toAdd.data = data;

        Document current = head;
        while (current.Next != null)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }
        current.Next = toAdd;
        size++;
    }

    public bool Pop()
    {
        Document tempNode = head;

        Document lastNode = null;
        int count = 0;

        if (size > 0)
        {
            while (tempNode != null)
            {
                if (count == size - 1)
                {
                    lastNode.Next = tempNode.Next;
                    return true;
                }
                count++;

                lastNode = tempNode;
                tempNode = tempNode.Next;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


public abstract class Document
{
    public Document Next;
    public Object data;

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public abstract string type();
}

public class WordDocument : Document
{
    public override string type()
    {
        return "docx";
    }
}

public class PdfDocument : Document
{
    public override string type()
    {
        return "pdf";
    }
}
```

This line causes the problem `Document toAdd = new Document();`

But I still could not find a way for **DisplayContents** function which will list all of the documents in the Print Queue, reporting both the Name and Type of each element Print Queue.

Could anyone review my code and help me to get it rectified as per the question. Highlight those areas where I have made mistakes.

Thanks

### UPDATE

the 2 questions i was trying to solve as follows

Question 1 : Write a class named Document to represent a document node in a print queue. it should contain a method name that returns the subject of the document and an abstract method called type that returns the document type . from document class derive two concrete classes named word document and pdf document.

Question 2 : Another class named Print Queue that is implemented as a linked list of Document objects. Print Queue should have a method named Push for adding a document to the end of the list, a method named pop for removing the first document from the list , and a method named DisplayContents for listing all of the documents in the Print Queue, reporting both the Name and Type of each element Print Queue should not use any standard library classes it should be own implementation of linked list.

here i like to post whatever at last i achieved. so please see the code and question let me know is it correct as per the 2 question pasted here.

### see the latest code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrintQueueDemo
{
    class PrintQueue
    {
        Node head;
        Node tail;

        /// <summary>
        /// add a document to the print queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strType">document type</param>
        /// <param name="strName">docunent name</param>
        public void Push(string strType, string strName)
        {
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = new Node(strType, strName);
                tail = head;
            }
            else
            {
                Node node = new Node(strType, strName);
                tail.setNext(node);
                tail = node;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// pop a document from the queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>null if printqueue is empty, else document</returns>
        public Node.Document Pop()
        {
            if (head == null)
                return null;

            Node.Document doc = new Node.Document(head.document.Type, head.document.Name);
            head = head.nextnode;
            if (head == null)
                tail = null;
            return doc;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get the current content of the queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string with current content (line per entry)</returns>
        public string DisplayContents()
        {
            string content = "";
            Node node = head;
            if (node == null)
                return "PrintQueue is empty";

            content = node.document.Name + ": " + node.document.Type;
            while (node.nextnode != null)
            {
                node = node.nextnode;
                content += "\r\n" + node.document.Name + ": " + node.document.Type;
            }
            return content;
        }

        public class Node
        {
            public Document document { get; private set; }
            public Node nextnode { get; private set; }

            public Node(string strType, string strName)
            {
                document = new Document(strType, strName);
            }

            public void setNext(Node node)
            {
                nextnode = node;
            }

            public class Document
            {
                public string Type { get; private set; }
                public string Name { get; private set; }

                public Document(string strType, string strName)
                {
                    Name = strName;
                    Type = strType;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PrintQueue pq = new PrintQueue();
pq.Push("cpp", "main.cpp");
pq.Push("c#", "main.cs");
pq.Push("c", "main.c");
pq.Push("h", "myinclude.h");

Console.WriteLine(pq.DisplayContents());
Console.WriteLine("===");

PrintQueue.Node.Document doc;
doc = pq.Pop();
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", doc.Name, doc.Type);
doc = pq.Pop();
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", doc.Name, doc.Type);
doc = pq.Pop();
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", doc.Name, doc.Type);
doc = pq.Pop();
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", doc.Name, doc.Type);
Console.WriteLine("===");

Console.WriteLine(pq.DisplayContents());
Console.WriteLine("===");

pq.Push("xls", "workbook.xls");
Console.WriteLine(pq.DisplayContents());
```

just tell me the above code will be accepted as per 2 question which i pasted at top. thanks

Comment: You defined `Document` as an abstract class, thus, you cannot create an instance of `Document` (in other words, it's illegal to write `new Document()` if `Document` is abstract)

Comment: You should re-define your method, `public void Push(Object data)` as `public void Push(Document toAdd)` and completely remove the lines `Document toAdd = new Document();` and `toAdd.data = data;`

Comment: i have one request that if possible can you come with rectified code and paste here. i guess if i try to update code then still be some issue. thanks

Comment: Your linked list has head but has no tail.

Comment: why tail is required....this is not double link list.

Comment: if my posted code is not right as per the question posted....then please come with right version of code because i am not good for the question. thanks

Comment: please see my update where i post the full latest code i build and please tell me will it be accepted as per the questions. thanks